# Using multiple colors for labelling that depend on values in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, color

I would like to do labelling like this (3 rows):

```
   Location_name
   Time
   People
```

My csv has 5 features

```
   Location_name      Time   AM/PM   People  A/K
```

Based on the value of "AM/PM", I want the "Time" has different colors; based on "A/K" values, I want the "People" had different colors.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with rule-based labeling

Select the layer properties of the layer that you are labeling and select the `Labels` tab. At the top, select `Rule-based labeling` and add a rule for each label (location, time, people). If you want to display a label for every item in the table, just don't add a filter to the rule.

[image: rule based labeling]

You will need to play with the placement properties of each label to position the labels such that they aren't right on top of each other. In my example I used an arbitrary distance of 5 just to make sure that the labels weren't on top of each other.

[image: label placement]

To get the custom coloring, go to the `Text` tab when editing the rule, and select the drop down next to the color and select `Edit...`

[image]

In the `Expression String Builder` that comes up you can put in an expression like the following

`if("t/f"='t', color_rgb(0,0,255), color_rgb(255,255,0))`

In this example, I have a column that is named "t/f" and contains a string value of 't' or 'f'. If the column value is 't', then the text is colored as blue, and otherwise is colored as yellow.

I did this to a sample layer where I had random values of t or f to colorize the strings. Display string is either red or green, and second display string is blue or yellow.

[image: end result]